# Is there any way to do sip_init; in same process for multiple threads in PJSIP stack?

Tags: c++, pjsip

I have been trying to do sip_init for multiple sip thread in pjsip stack, but i am not able init for multi threads and if possible then how can we get values of different threads from same variables.

I am adding here the code that i have tried with.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjmedia.h>
#include <pjmedia-codec.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjsip_simple.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
static __thread trunk_t *sip_trunk;

static void *sip_init(trunk_t *trunk)
{
  pj_pool_t *pool = NULL;
  pj_status_t status;
  pjmedia_codec_mgr *codec_mgr;

  int i;
  struct event *ev;
  struct timeval tv;
  struct in_addr listen_addr;
  sip_trunk = trunk;

  /* Must init PJLIB first: */

  status = pj_init();
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  pj_log_set_level(5);

  /* Then init PJLIB-UTIL: */
  status = pjlib_util_init();
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  pj_caching_pool_init(&cp, &pj_pool_factory_default_policy, 0);
  sip_thread_reg_process();

  tv.tv_sec = 0;
  tv.tv_usec = 100000;
  ev = event_new(trunk->rt_thr_ess->proto_evbase, -1,   EV_READ|EV_PERSIST, rx_data, NULL);
  event_add(ev, &tv);

  /* Create global endpoint: */
  const pj_str_t *hostname;
  const char *endpt_name;

  /* Endpoint MUST be assigned a globally unique name.
   * The name will be used as the hostname in Warning header.
   */

  /* For this implementation, we'll use hostname for simplicity */
  hostname = pj_gethostname();
  endpt_name = hostname->ptr;

  /* Create the endpoint: */

  status = pjsip_endpt_create(&cp.factory, endpt_name, &g_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /* 
   * Add UDP transport, with hard-coded port 
   * Alternatively, application can use pjsip_udp_transport_attach()    to
   * start UDP transport, if it already has an UDP socket (e.g. after   it
   * resolves the address with STUN).
   */
  pj_sockaddr addr;
  pjsip_tpfactory *tpfactory;
  for(i=0; i < 1; ++i) {
    listen_addr.s_addr = trunk->listen_ip;
    pj_str_t ip_str = pj_str(strdup(inet_ntoa(listen_addr)));
    pj_sockaddr_init(AF, &addr, &ip_str, (pj_uint16_t)trunk- >listen_port);

    if(AF == pj_AF_INET()) {
      status = pjsip_udp_transport_start( g_endpt, &addr.ipv4, NULL,
               1, &transport[i]);

      status = pjsip_tcp_transport_start( g_endpt, &addr.ipv4, 1, &  tpfactory);
    } else if(AF == pj_AF_INET6()) {
      status = pjsip_udp_transport_start6(g_endpt, &addr.ipv6, NULL,
               1, NULL);
    } else {
      status = PJ_EAFNOTSUP;
    }
    if(status != PJ_SUCCESS) {
      app_perror(THIS_FILE, "Unable to start UDP transport", status);

return NULL;
    }
  }

  /* 
   * Init transaction layer.
   * This will create/initialize transaction hash tables etc.
   */
  status = pjsip_tsx_layer_init_module(g_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /* 
   * Initialize UA layer module.
   * This will create/initialize dialog hash tables etc.
   */
  status = pjsip_ua_init_module( g_endpt, NULL );
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /* 
   * Init invite session module.
   * The invite session module initialization takes additional  argument,

   * i.e. a structure containing callbacks to be called on specific
   * occurence of events.
   *
   * The on_state_changed and on_new_session callbacks are mandatory.
   * Application must supply the callback function.
   *
   * We use on_media_update() callback in this application to start
   * media transmission.
   */
  pjsip_inv_callback inv_cb;

  /* Init the callback for INVITE session: */
  pj_bzero(&inv_cb, sizeof(inv_cb));
  inv_cb.on_state_changed = &call_on_state_changed;

  inv_cb.on_new_session = &call_on_forked;
  inv_cb.on_media_update = &call_on_media_update;
  inv_cb.on_rx_offer = &call_on_rx_offer;

  /* Initialize invite session module:  */
  status = pjsip_inv_usage_init(g_endpt, &inv_cb);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /* Initialize 100rel support */
  status = pjsip_100rel_init_module(g_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /*
   * Register our module to receive incoming requests.
   */
  status = pjsip_endpt_register_module(g_endpt, &mod_ics);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /*
   * Register message logger module.
   */
  status = pjsip_endpt_register_module( g_endpt, &msg_logger);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /* 
   * Initialize media endpoint.
   * This will implicitly initialize PJMEDIA too.
   */
  status = pjmedia_endpt_create(&cp.factory,
      pjsip_endpt_get_ioqueue(g_endpt),
      0, &g_med_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

/* Initializing g711 codec */
#if CODEC_G711  
  status = pjmedia_codec_g711_init(g_med_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

  /*
   * Setting PCMA as the Highest priority codec */
  codec_mgr = pjmedia_endpt_get_codec_mgr(g_med_endpt);
  pj_str_t codec_id = pj_str("PCMA/8000/1");
  pjmedia_codec_mgr_set_codec_priority(codec_mgr, &codec_id,  PJMEDIA_CODEC_PRIO_HIGHEST);
#endif

  /* Initializing g722 codec */
#if CODEC_G722  
  status = pjmedia_codec_g722_init(g_med_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);
#endif

#if CODEC_G729  
  /* Initializing g729 codec */
  status = pjmedia_codec_g729_init(g_med_endpt);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);
#endif
#endif
  pool = pjsip_endpt_create_pool(g_endpt, "Generic Pool", 512, 512);
  pj_str_t realm_str = pj_str("google.com");

  status = pjsip_auth_srv_init(pool, &auth_server, &realm_str,     digest_lookup, PJSIP_AUTH_SRV_IS_PROXY);
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);

#if ENABLE_VIDEO
  /* Only for Video this video format manager creation done */
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, 1);
#endif

#if H264_CODE
  PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(status == PJ_SUCCESS, NULL);
#endif

 return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  trunk_t *sip_trunk;
  trunk_t *sip_anthr_trunk;
  pthread_t sid;
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&sid, NULL, sip_init, sip_trunk);
  pthread_join(sid, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, sip_init, sip_anthr_trunk);
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us (with code) what you have tried to do?

Comment: I have added the code that i have tried with.